# Adding custom options in my dotnet CLI tool

Tags: c#, json, .net, command-line-interface

I created a new CLI tool to play around.
In the proj file I added the below line

```
<ToolCommandName>helloworld</ToolCommandName>
```

This allows me run the CLI tool with just “helloworld” instead of writing dotnet run helloworld.

Now I want to have my custom options as well, like -name -place

```
helloworld -name mark -place Virginia
```

How to do achieve this kind of detailing?

Comment: It's easiest to use a library to parse command-line options. I like [Mono.Options](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/main/XPlat/Mono.Options), but there's also [System.CommandLine and System.CommandLine.DragonFruit](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api) and [McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils) etc

Comment: See my [simple example here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/command-line-samples/tree/master/AgeApp) which shows how to do parameters and help. Note this is done using .NET Core 5, C# 9 and should work with newer versions of .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a comprehensive example of a functional dotnet CLI tool at the following repository: https://github.com/bnayae/Event-Sourcing-Backbone-Template.

The power of the modern dotnet CLI lies within a few key sections. It utilizes a meta project structure responsible for the CLI package (NuGet) and the actual content, typically consisting of a project or solution along with a metadata folder.

By visiting the provided link, you can examine the Event-Sourcing-Backbone-Templates.csproj file, which handles the packaging of the CLI.

Inside the templates/Skeleton folder, you can explore the content and metadata associated with the CLI tool.

The metadata resides in the .template.config folder, with the primary file being template.json. This file allows you to define the configuration and add switches to your CLI tool. Furthermore, you can customize the representation of switches by suggesting custom shortcuts and similar modifications within the dotnetcli.host.json file.